# How to merge two different local branch in git, one of the branch has not commited

Tags: git

I have clone a repository from github, Let's  call it A, which has branch **master**

then I created a different branch **dev** locally, later on, I add some files and commited to **dev**.

today, unexpected, I add and modify some files, when I commit to github, git says :

> the remote contains work that you do not have locally.

I realize that the branch is in **master**, not the **dev**, so I checkout the **dev** branch, but the new files are gone.

I don't want to commit the new change to the master branch, but dev branch, so I wonder if I can merge the local changes in master to dev branch?

Update:
I switched back to master branch, and `git status` shows *On branch master, nothing to commit*, the command `git push origin dev` shows *Everything up to date*, that's weird.

The `git reflog` in master branch shows below:

```
5575415 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from dev to master  
696c7c5 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to dev  
5575415 HEAD@{2}: commit (amend): update  
1669e5d HEAD@{3}: commit: update  
696c7c5 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from dev to master  
696c7c5 HEAD@{5}: commit (initial): init dev branch
```

The `git reflog` in dev branch shows below:

```
696c7c5 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to dev  
5575415 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from dev to master  
696c7c5 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to dev  
5575415 HEAD@{3}: commit (amend): update  
1669e5d HEAD@{4}: commit: update  
696c7c5 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from dev to master  
696c7c5 HEAD@{6}: commit (initial): init dev branch
```

Comment: Can you cherry pick your commits over from master?

Comment: @haolly, can you post the contents of your reflog using the command `git reflog`? If the list is long, the last 25 entries or so should be sufficient. This will help determine the exact sequence of actions.

Comment: @KevinBurdett  Thanks for your response, I posted the output in question

Comment: @Dezza It works !  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fast forward (git pull) merge here.

1. Be on your dev branch first.
2. Then git fetch origin master
3. Then git merge origin/master
4. Finally git commit to commit the merge

This is done because Git can't merge the changes from master to your dev branch. These are two different branches hence fast forward (or git pull) can't be done. You have to fetch first the master branch and then merge it with the dev branch.

Comment: But the local changes in master has not been pushed to the remote, and I don't want to push it

Comment: You don't have to push it here also.. git commit will only commit to your local repository. Also git fetch origin master will just fetch the master branch so that you can merge to your local dev repository